# Angular dist file lib javascript file changed names. What could have influenced this?

Tags: angular, apache, maven, deployment, chunks

I started working with an application that is currently on the client's production environment at version 1.0.2. A colleague of mine made some changes in the UI (Angular) part (just to fix a tab/button layout), fixed some Maven dependencies with high severity and delivered the changes to the client, with the version 1.0.3.

The client then restarted the Apache server in their quality environment to restart the UI after the 1.0.3 version has been installed on the server and the UI is not working anymore, as Apache logs show the following error (yellow square to hide client's information):
[image]

So basically, there are error codes AH00128 saying files do not exist.

The thing is, up to 1.0.2 these files existed in the dist folder before (dist/lib/gi-ui-1.0.x), for example:

[image]

However, in the 1.0.3 version in seems these js files have changed their names:

[image]

As you can see, now they have different names and it looks like the Apache server is looking for the old ones

The content of these files are all something like this:

[image]

What could be the cause for this?
Is it normal for these js files to change their names? How can we influence these changes? By changing the application code in the UI?
Is it normal for after restarting the Apache server, looking for these kind of files and expecting them to always have the same name?

Thank you